# Why am I getting "Resource not found" when querying reporting web service O365 API for Message Tracing?

Tags: office365, o365rwsclient

I'm looking to programmatically access Message Traces using the Reporting Web Service API that O365 provides.

More specifically, I'd like to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/o365-enterprise-developers/jj984335(v=office.15)) API route to access that information since I have not seen any other API/API Route that supports tracing of messages.

However, when I do the following `cURL`,

```
curl "https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace" -u "<my email address>"
```

I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code /><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Resource not found for the segment 'MessageTrace'.</m:message></m:error>
```

I have verified that my authentication is working as intended and I can't use .NET for my use case so I can't use the rwsclient library, unfortunately.

Is this API route no longer valid? Or am I just querying the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was because my account didn't have permission to access that endpoint. If you're also looking to figure this out, make sure your account has permission!